# MySQL Merged table duplicates

Tags: mysql, merge, duplicates

Here is what I currently have:

Archive tables (one for each year, 2008-2011) and 4 newly created tables for 2012 broken into quarters.  All of these tables, including the new one, have the same structure and keys.  The naming convention for these is ARCHIVE_PLAYS.  I then have a "live" table (Called PLAYS) for current data.  I have a merged table that combines all tables so that I can run reports.  The issue I have, which I didn't have before, is that this merged table is showing duplicates.  They have the same Primary keys so this shouldn't be the case, right?  It must have something to do with the new tables I just created as I didn't have this issue before.

Structure:

```
**COMPANY**
      COMPANY.MERGED_PLAYS
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2008
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2009
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2010
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2011
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2012Q1
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2012Q2
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2012Q3
      COMPANY.ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2012Q4

**COMPANY2**
      COMPANY2.PLAYS
```

Each table, with the exception of the Merged_Plays, has the following Create:

```
CREATE TABLE `ARCHIVE_PLAYS_2011` (
`ENTRY_ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`NODE_ID` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
`HW_ID` VARBINARY(64) NOT NULL,
`LOG_DAY` DATE NOT NULL,
`ROW_NUMBER` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`NODE_NAME` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
`FILE_NAME` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
`PRESENTATION_NAME` VARCHAR(1024) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SMIL_SEQUENCE_ID` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SMIL_CONTENT_ID` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PLAY_TIME_MS` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`PLAY_TIME` TIME NOT NULL,
`STATUS_CODE` VARCHAR(48) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`NUM_SCREENS_CONNECTED_AND_ON` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`NUM_SPEAKERS_CONNECTED_AND_ON` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SCREEN_LAYOUT_MATCHES` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ENTRY_PROCESSED` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FILE_PATH` VARCHAR(1024) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`NODE_ID`, `LOG_DAY`, `ROW_NUMBER`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_ENTRY_ID` (`ENTRY_ID`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_LOG_DAY` (`LOG_DAY`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_LOG_DAY_PLAY_TIME` (`LOG_DAY`, `PLAY_TIME`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_FILE_NAME` (`FILE_NAME`(600)),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_NODE_NAME` (`NODE_NAME`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_FILE_NAME_NODE_NAME` (`FILE_NAME`(600), `NODE_NAME`),
INDEX `PLAYLOG_ENTRY_ID_PROCESSED` (`ENTRY_ID`, `ENTRY_PROCESSED`)
  )
    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the DDL and knowing how you transferred the data to the archive tables and how you are managing the primary keys.  A primary key is only guaranteed to be unique within a table.

Comment: I took the Create Table code from one of the previous archive tables to make each table.  I then did an INSERT statement from PLAYS and used BETWEEN to get the dates in the quarter.

Answer (score 1):

A primary key only assures unique data within a single table.  You must have duplicate records across multiple tables.  Make sure you have deleted all of the 2012 data from the live table.  Make sure there are no dups between any of the quarter tables.

Also if the records are 100% dups, if you do a UNION between all of your tables (instead of UNION ALL) you will get unique results, however this will decrease query performance.

Comment: Thanks.  The idea, of course, is to delete 2012 from the live table but I didn't want to do that until I was sure all data was backed up and archived.

Comment: If you haven't removed the 2012 data from the live table that would explain why you have dups.  Wouldn't all of the data in the 2012 quarters tables also be in the live table?

Comment: Correct.  I'm rather new to MySQL and I inherited all of these tables when I started here.  I was under the impression I wouldn't have the dupes because there was an original 2012 archive table that was Jan-July that didn't have them when I ran queries on it months ago.  I guess it was different in structure or the merged table didn't actually include it.